# Клик по блоку и всплывающее сообщение(не работает)

Tags: javascript

В контейнере должно быть 5 блоков(ячейки), по клику на блок появляется alert.

```js
var div, container = document.getElementById('container');
   
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 div = document.createElement('div');
  div.onClick = function() {
   alert("Ячейка " + i);
  }
  container.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
#container {
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  }
#container div {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: див котрый вы вставляете не отображается изза отсутствия высоты и ширины, и правильно не `onClick` а `onclick`, "с" маленькая

Comment: Нет не из-за этого, а этого: "TypeError: container is null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот смотрите, все работает

```js
var div, container = document.getElementById('container');

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.onclick = function() {
    alert("Ячейка " + i);
  }
  container.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
#container {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#container div {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

если у вас всетаки `TypeError: container is null` , проверте, есть ли елемент с ид `container` + проверте когда именно вы запускаете код, возможно вы не дожыдаетесь подгрузки ДОМ, в таком случаи можно сделать так :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
  // тут ваш код
});
```

Comment: Да вы правы, спасибо разобрался. По коду в файле .html, JS  обрабатывался раньше, чем HTML.